# Generate a multi variable polynomial in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have several lists with the coefficients of some multivariate polynomials, and I need to write them in a polynomial form. For example, for the code below

```
from sympy import Poly

list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

x = sym.Symbol('x')
y = sym.Symbol('y')
print(Poly([0,1,2,3,4,5],x,y))
```

I want to have printed x+2*x*y+3*x^2+4*y+5*y^2. But I am getting this error `sympy.polys.polyerrors.MultivariatePolynomialError: 'list' representation not supported` Can someone help me with this? Thank you!